# Differences between an extension and a module?

Tags: magento

Both extend the features and functionality of Magento, but what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've finally found the answer.

Extensions are simply packed modules. In other words, you extend the features and functionality of Magento by writing a module. Then you have a choice to leave it as it is or pack it up (`System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions`). An extension (a packed module) is then published on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect).

Answer (score 0):

The Main difference between extension and module is that, when you create any extension it can be for community as well and can be used by others installing simple package as it is. And module are something that is part of core magento it can be for your own purpose and for others too. Not necessarily you will create package of it to have it work .

In Most cases solely you will use them

Answer (score -3):

The main difference is that you can realize the main functional with an extension or a component. And with a module you realize an additional functional. Extensions include modules, or modules extend components.